# Azure App Services Sonarqube With Azure SQL DB Issues

Tags: azure, sonarqube, azure-web-app-service

1. We deployed Azure App Service with docker as Sonarqube using portal and we are able to access the url.
2. After we created the projects if we will restart/stop & start Azure App Service, which ever I created initially projects is not showing/disappering.
   3.We are using Azure SQL DB and also we provided the JDBC details accordingly.

After Restart the Azure App Service and Before Restart the Azure App Service.
[image]
[image]

1. Could you please help on how to pass the Azure SQL DB to Sonarqube Azure App Service Connection string.
   [image]

Comment: You can refer to [Connect the App to the Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-dotnetcore-sqldb-app?tabs=azure-portal%2Cvisualstudio-deploy%2Cdeploy-instructions-azure-portal%2Cazure-portal-logs%2Cazure-portal-resources#5---connect-the-app-to-the-database), [Configure connection strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-common?tabs=portal#configure-connection-strings) and [SonarQube-AzureAppService](https://github.com/vanderby/SonarQube-AzureAppService)

Comment: You can also refer to similar issues [Sonar + MS SQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13208124/sonar-ms-sql-database) and  [How to configure SonarQube to connect to Azure SQL Database to generate reports](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/how-to-configure-sonarqube-to-connect-to-azure-sql-database-to-generate-reports/16047)

Comment: @DeepDave-MT Thanks for your information
I had done same process which you proivded links to me
"During oprations After Restart the Azure App Service and Before Restart the Azure App Service i lost my project data on sonarqube dashboard"
How can we resolve this and it is related to db connectivity  or someting else?